# It's possible to use Typescript in Magento PWA Studio?

Tags: pwa

I'm starting to study the PWA Studio, and I enjoy using Typescript. So I want to know if it's possible to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript compiles down to Javascript so technically there's no reason you **can't** that I'm aware of but it won't be a pleasant experience as core Magento does not use TS therefore you'll either need to work without types for changes to the core or add them yourself.

Some people within Magento want to add Typescript support but I'm not currently sure if it will be going ahead or not.

> I'm currently working on a proposal to add typescript to the repo. Im going to close this issue for now but will continue to reference it internally and in my proposal moving forward.

Taken from https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio/issues/2171#issuecomment-771031828